# jquery select section by it's own index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i select the third section, and add new section before it?

**Before:**

```
<article id="container">
    <section> a </section>
    <section> b </section>
    <section> d </section>
    <section> e </section>
</article>
```

**After:**

```
<article id="container">
    <section> a </section>
    <section> b </section>
    <section> c </section>
    <section> d </section>
    <section> e </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$( target ).before( content )](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [**$( content ).insertBefore( target )**](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) as shown below:

```js
$('<section> c </section>').insertBefore('#container > section:eq(2)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="container">
    <section> a </section>
    <section> b </section>
    <section> d </section>
    <section> e </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.after()` selector:

```
$("#container section:eq(1)").after($("<section>cc</section>"));
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/65yzzwdd/)**

Comment: Well, that's technically not correct. He wants to add a new section **before** the **third** element. So `$("#article section:eq(2)").before($("<section>cc</section"));` would be more correct. Your solution won't work, if there is anything in between the second and third section

Comment: Isn't before third element means after second element??

Comment: Not if there is anything in between them, like a div or anything

Comment: also if that lies, then it will be one of the element in list.

Comment: Well, not in this example, but i guess he won't use this exact example in his project.

Comment: first, thank you a lot guies!! More over, as @Markai said, i want to add before, and i have more sections in those child sections.

Comment: if you have more section before then one with text section d is not third child. which is wrong.

Comment: i dont have more section before the third, i ment that every one of them is use as a container for another sections

Comment: which will still brake if you use `.before()`

Answer (score 2):

Using `eq`

```
$newSection = $("<section>c</section>");
$("#container section").eq(2).before($newSection);
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/ , https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Demo `-->`  https://jsfiddle.net/2f7n1r06/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)  and  [:nth-child - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select the third section.

```js
// Create a new, plain <section> element
var sp1 = document.createElement("section");
sp1.innerHTML ="c";
// Get a reference to the element, before we want to insert the element
var sp2 = document.querySelector("#container section:nth-child(3)");//he third section 
// Get a reference to the parent element
var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

// Insert the new element into the DOM before sp2
parentDiv.insertBefore(sp1, sp2);
```

```html
<article id="container">
    <section> a </section>
    <section> b </section>
    <section> d </section>
    <section> e </section>
</article>
```